# How can I tell phantomJS to skip a section of a page when it compiles?

Tags: phantomjs, yeti-launch

I have a site that uses the Yeti Launch app from Zurb to compile my site and make a dist version of it. However Yeti fails in building the site because phantomjs returns a (correct) error when compiling an external javascript file (the addthis plugin). So my question is, how can I tell phantom to skip a couple of lines of code? Much like a  in HTML?

The line that makes phantom angry:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57056d887bbc9401"></script>
```

The error I get from Yeti:

> $ TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'e.split')
>   $ http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57056d887bbc9401:1 in i
>   $ http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57056d887bbc9401:6
>   $ http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57056d887bbc9401:2
>   $ http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57056d887bbc9401:9
>   $ http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57056d887bbc9401:2 in r
>   $ http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57056d887bbc9401:5
>   $ http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57056d887bbc9401:5
>   $ Ended execution of digitaliserad.nu.